# class for jquery ui datepicker button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have the following code for the jQuery UI datepicker:

```
$(function() {
        $(".date").datepicker({
            showOn: 'button',
            buttonText: "Choose Date",
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
        });
    });
```

It creates a button on the side of the text box so people can click the box and select a date.  Is it possible to apply a class to the button that is created so I can apply a CSS style to it?

Answer (score 25):

You can't add an additional class through an option, but it does have a class: `ui-datepicker-trigger`, so if you just style directly or as a descendant of an identifiable container it'll work, for example:

```
.ui-datepicker-trigger { color: red; }
//or...
.myContainer .ui-datepicker-trigger { color: red; }
```

Or, add a different class to the button manually after creating the datepicker (which creates the button):

```
$(function() {
    $(".date").datepicker({
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonText: "Choose Date",
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    }).next(".ui-datepicker-trigger").addClass("someClass");
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It work as:

   .ui-datepicker-trigger {color:red;}

No need to put the .dateContainer

Comment: @Doug - I wasn't sure if you wanted it more specific or not, just giving you options :) glad either approach was what you were looking for :)

Comment: It's better more specific sometimes because you may have more that one datepicker on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

Make it become a jQuery UI button since you already have the framework loaded ;)

http://www.robertmullaney.com/2011/08/26/make-jquery-datepicker-use-ui-button/

Disclaimer: My Blog