# Adding customized button with Jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a datepicker with my own styled button, and I would like to have the calendar open only if the user clicks the button and not if the user clicks inside the text-box.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929600/class-for-jquery-ui-datepicker-button) describes how to add a button using existing jquery datepicker functionality and then add classes to that Jquery button. However I thought it would be simpler in my case to just add a 'show' method to my own styled button, and disable the focus event in jquery datepicker.

The following code does not work, however - the calendar still opens if the user clicks inside the text-box.

```
<input class="form-control" id="np_OpenDate" value="">                      
 <div id="np_btn_OpenDate" class="btn btn-icon"><i class="icon icon-calendar"></i></div> 

$('#np_OpenDate').datepicker().focus(
    function() {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
);
$('#np_btn_OpenDate').click(function() {
    $('#np_OpenDate').datepicker('show');
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achieve the desired result by setting datepicker showOn option to "none".

```
$('#np_OpenDate').datepicker( {
   format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
     autoclose: true,
    showOn: "none"
  });
```

Comment: Beautiful and no hacks! Thanks very much

Comment: I am so glad that finally it works, sometimes less is more:)

Answer (score 1):

Your functiom should be :

```
$('#np_OpenDate').datepicker().focus(
    function(ev) {    
   //here you hide the div that appears
   $(".datepicker").hide();
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I hid the datepicker with `$('#ui-datepicker-div').hide();` which seems to work (I had originally done `$('#np_OpenDate').datepicker('hide');` - but this caused the datepicker to "flash" on the screen.) The only problem is that now the button to open the datepicker doesn't work, because the button triggers the focus() which then closes it again. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately pressing the button triggers the event object to have tagName INPUT as well...

Comment: So ask about the event id.

Comment: This doesn't help. The logical sequence is as follows: User presses Button. The Button triggers the datepicker focus. The function(ev) picks up the event object of the *datepicker* focus. The button press is past history!

Comment: Try to use $('#np_OpenDate').focus() without .datepicker, when you are clicking the button  $('#np_OpenDate').datepicker('show'); trigger the focus event?

Comment: Thanks for keeping trying! However there is no improvement when I remove the datepicker as you suggest...

Comment: You shall wrap the elements with a div and initialize the datepicker on the div so when you trigger  $('#wrap_div').datepicker('show'); the focus function won't trigger, I really don't get why $('#np_OpenDate').datepicker('show'); trigger the focus event I tried it and it worked for me.

Comment: Sorry - I tried it and it doesn't work for me... Maybe tomorrow I will try again and perhaps create a fiddle...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187565/discussion-between-gordon613-and-richard-socker).